# Is there a way to parse a single column into multiple columns using python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to python still and am learning.  I'm working a csv file and would like to manipulate the data by parsing a single column into multiple columns, by splitting the values of that single column into several different columns.  Here's an example

```
Old Column                            **New Columns**

|**column 1**|          |**column 1**| **column 2** | **column 3**|

   value 1                  Value 1       Value 2        Value 3    
   value 2    
   value 3
```

** sorry if this reads like crap... for some reason the spacing is all jacked up when trying to post my query here on stackoverflow

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code?

Comment: with pandas you could try to use `pivot` or `transpose`. Pandas doc: [reshaping](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html)